# AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler does not trigger for AutomationElement.NameProperty

Tags: c#, automation, ui-automation

I'm trying to detect if the `AutomationElement.NameProperty` of an icon element in the taskbar has changed, but the event does not trigger at all. How can I work around this? I don't want to have to manually check the name every few seconds.

```
public class WatchInternet: Context
    {
        AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler wifiChangedHandler;
        AutomationElement wifiIcon;
        string? oldName;
        public WatchInternet()
        {
            AutomationElement taskbar = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.TreeScope_Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Taskbar"));
            AutomationElement rightSection = taskbar.FindFirst(TreeScope.TreeScope_Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "303"));
            wifiIcon = taskbar.FindFirst(TreeScope.TreeScope_Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "{7820AE74-23E3-4229-82C1-E41CB67D5B9C}"));
            wifiChangedHandler = new AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(WifiChanged);
            Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(wifiIcon, TreeScope.TreeScope_Element, wifiChangedHandler, AutomationElement.NameProperty);
        }

        void WifiChanged(object? sender, AutomationPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string newName = wifiIcon.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.NameProperty).ToString()!;
            if (newName == oldName) return;
            oldName = newName;
            //Do stuff
        }
    }

//WifiChanged event never gets called
```

Comment: Not a work around but it's likely that control is being created and destroyed and a new element is backing the control each time. You should check the InstanceId to see if it's a new control as the icon changes.